# How can I count the number of items in div that are hidden?

Tags: jquery, css, variables

How can I count the number of items in div that are hidden using Jquery?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think that

```
$("#someElement > *").filter(":hidden").size();
```

will work.

Updated: Added the '*'. Note that this will select the immediate children of `#someElement`.

Comment: Nope, this will return 1, if #someElement is hidden, 0 otherwise.

Answer (score 19):

Direct children of someElement that are hidden:

```
$('#someElement > :hidden').length;
```

Any descendants of someElement that are hidden:

```
$('#someElement :hidden').length;
```

If you already have a jQuery object you can use it as the context:

```
var ele = $('#someElement');

$(':hidden', ele).length;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#someElement *:hidden").size()
```