# How do I count the number of hidden divs of a certain class with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a dynamic form that I've written in rails. I want to be sure that a user can add no more than five links.

I start with two links and I have another link that allows the user to add another field. I also have a link next to the links that allows the user to remove a field, which sets a hidden field and then hides the field with slideUp();.

I want to know if there are 5 fields on the screen that the user is hoping to submit.

Here's what I'm currently using - this just counts all of the divs with that classname.

```
if($(".classname").length <5){
//create element dynamically
}
```

I want to check if "style='display: none;'" How might I do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jquery count number of hidden elements within div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1295956/jquery-count-number-of-hidden-elements-within-div)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the [`:hidden`](http://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/) selector:

```
if ($(".classname:hidden").length < 5) {
    //create element dynamically
}
```

This will return any element with that class which is not viewable to the user.  If you just want to check for `display:none`, then use [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/):

```
$(".classname").filter(function () {
    return $(this).css("display") == "none";
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this

```
$('.classname:not([style*="display: none"])').length
```